# [About parameters effect LWE and SIS to be computation or perfect secure]

Tags: lattice-crypto, lwe, ring-lwe, sis

Hello I am new to lattice cryptography
I am reading the paper [More Efficient Commitments from
Structured Lattice Assumptions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/997.pdf) 
They define bound B in page 3 
[image]

Then In figure 1 in page 9 
[image]

Can someone kindly explain why the bound increase/decrease will change the LWE/SIS from computation hard to statistical hard? (It seems to me it make sense that the changing of bound will effect the hardness, but I can not get why it will change it from computation hard to statistical hard) 
TIA